# Angular-dragdrop or jQueryUI calculating droppable area offset incorrectly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop, sitecore, jquery-ui-droppable

Been trying to use angular-dragdrop, but the droppable area that is created isn't the same size as the div (it is both taller and wider), and sits directly underneath where it should be. I have a feeling it's calculating the offsets incorrectly, but I'm not exactly sure how, nor how to fix it.

Here is the directive (pardon the bad formatting and possibly bad practices):

```
mainApp.directive("mppDroppableLogo", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'src/slides/editing/mppDroppableLogo.tpl.html',
    controller: 'mppDroppableLogoController',
    scope: {
        imageUrlChanged: '&'
    },
    compile: function compile(element, attributes) {
        return {
            pre: function preLink(scope, element, attributes, controller) { },
            post: function postLink(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
                var sitecoreImage = element.find('img');
                var imageWrapper = element.find(".mpp-droppable-logo");

                if (!angular.isDefined(imageWrapper)) {
                    console.log("mppDroppable:pgp directive is missing.");
                }

                if (angular.isDefined(sitecoreImage)) {

                    var styling = sitecoreImage.attr('style');
                    if (angular.isDefined(styling)) {
                        imageWrapper.attr("style", styling);

                    }

                    $scope.originalImageUrl = sitecoreImage.attr("src");
                    var cssUrl = "url(\'" + sitecoreImage.attr("src") + "\')";
                    imageWrapper.css("background-image", cssUrl);

                }

                imageWrapper.css("background-size", "contain");
                imageWrapper.css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
            }
        };
    }
};
})
```

And its partial HTML:

```
<div data-drop="true" 
data-jqyoui-options="{
    hoverClass: 'valid-item-being-dragged',
    tolerance: 'touch'
}"
jqyoui-droppable="{
    onDrop: 'changeUrl(event, ui)'
}" 
class="mpp-droppable-logo"
ng-click="toggleSidebar()">

<!-- Hidden original image generated by Sitecore -->
<div ng-transclude ng-hide="true"></div>
</div>
```

This is used to wrap a sitecore image tag in an XSLT:

```
  <div style="top: 26vw; left: 6vw;">
    <mpp-droppable-logo image-url-changed="settings.imageUrlChanged" field-name="Logo">
      <sc:image field="Logo" style="width: 16vw; height: 5.5vw;" />
    </mpp-droppable-logo>
  </div>
```

So what happens is that the directive gets compiled, hides the sitecore image tag, and then fills the div that wraps it (imageWrapper in the post compile, the div defined in the partial HTML with data-drop=true) with stylings to imitate an image tag. I've included an image below, with bad MS Paint skills to cover up proprietary stuff. The yellow-bordered div represents where the droppable area SHOULD be, and is only shown when a valid draggable asset enters the droppable area. The black square is the image I'm currently dragging - as you can see, we're way out of the bounds of the droppable area. The blue rectangle represents approximately the bounds of where the actual droppable area is.

http://gyazo.com/948852b8c96d3c6f3eeccec5ba2e11d9

If it's any use:

- removing the "top" and "left" styles from the outer wrapper will move the image up to the top left (obviously), but the droppable area will now also somewhat overlap the div, so you can drag images directly onto it, but you can also drag images slightly below it and the proper event will fire.
- removing the hidden sitecore image tag after transferring over the styles doesn't change the droppable area's size or placement
- Jquery offset() on the div gives: top=449 and left=367. Jquery position() on the div gives top=0, left=0.

Anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be?